# Show different image of hover in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, mousehover

I want to show different image on hover of div in react with usestate. Issue is when i hover on single image then all images changed. How to handle this issue. Screenshots of hover result are attached

```
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

<div className="container-fluid" id="companies">
  <div className="row">
    <div className="col-md-3 p-0">
      <div className="company-block" onMouseOver={() => setOpen(true)} onMouseOut={() => setOpen(false)}>
        <Image src={open ? BlockFiBlack : BlockFiWhite}/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div className="col-md-3 p-0">
      <div className="company-block" onMouseOver={() => setOpen(true)} onMouseOut={() => setOpen(false)}>
        <Image src={open ? NerdWalletBlack : NerdWalletWhite}/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div className="col-md-3 p-0">
      <div className="company-block" onMouseOver={() => setOpen(true)} onMouseOut={() => setOpen(false)}>
        <Image src={open ? SuperRateBlack : SuperRateWhite}/>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div className="col-md-3 p-0">
       <div className="company-block" onMouseOver={() => setOpen(true)} onMouseOut={() => setOpen(false)}>
          <Image src={open ? XealBlack : XealWhite}/>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Before div hover result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K02mJ.png)
[After div hover result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohBvA.png)

Answer (score 2):

move individual items like following to separate component

```
<div className="col-md-3 p-0">
      <div className="company-block" onMouseOver={() => setOpen(true)} onMouseOut={() => setOpen(false)}>
        <Image src={open ? BlockFiBlack : BlockFiWhite}/>
      </div>
    </div>
```

and manage open state there.

this would work fine that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a string instead of a boolean to set which image is currently hovered.

```
const [open, setOpen] = useState('');

const unhover = () => {
  setOpen('')
}

<div className="container-fluid" id="companies">
  <div className="row">
    <div className="col-md-3 p-0">
      <div className="company-block" onMouseOver={() => setOpen('blockfi')} onMouseOut={unhover}>
        <Image src={open === 'blockfi' ? BlockFiBlack : BlockFiWhite}/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div className="col-md-3 p-0">
      <div className="company-block" onMouseOver={() => setOpen('nerdwallet')} onMouseOut={unhover}>
        <Image src={open === 'nerdwallet' ? NerdWalletBlack : NerdWalletWhite}/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div className="col-md-3 p-0">
      <div className="company-block" onMouseOver={() => setOpen('superrate')} onMouseOut={unhover}>
        <Image src={open === 'superrate' ? SuperRateBlack : SuperRateWhite}/>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div className="col-md-3 p-0">
       <div className="company-block" onMouseOver={() => setOpen('xeal')} onMouseOut={unhover}>
          <Image src={open === 'xeal' ? XealBlack : XealWhite}/>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```